# Passing rng to Distributions

Tags: julia

I am using [Distributions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl) since the julia standard library does not support all necessary distributions 
Within 1 special function I need the same random numbers. I am looking for a way to use always the same random number generator for this part, but don't now how to pass it to Distributions.jl
Using `srand` is not want I want, since then the global rng is reset.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Distributions API currently supports this although it should. You may want to ask on the julia-stats list or file an issue on the project repo.

Comment: I found an relating issue https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/issues/197

Comment: Could you provide example code of what you're trying to do? Usually you wouldn't want to explicitly reset the RNG, you'd want to store the intermediate value and reuse it.

Comment: To get reproducible results for e.g. cross-validation or stochastic optimisation.

Comment: srand can be fine for that. Can you provide example _code_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not yet possible, due to the fact that Distributions.jl currently uses the Rmath library for this (see https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/issues/197), but it is on the to-do list.